# How to get the top three elements from a list in Python? (Vowels)

Tags: python, loops, element

I'm currently doing a course in Python (extreme noob/ beginner level), but accidentally wrote a code that gives one country with the most vowels, while I needed to get the top three countries with the most vowels.
This is what I currently used to get one country only:

```
def most_vowels(countries):
    vowels = ["A", "a", "E", "e", "I", "i", "O", "o", "U", "u"]
    vowel_list = []
    for country in countries:
        length_vowels = len(set(country).intersection(set(vowels))) 
        vowel_list.append(length_vowels)
    max_vowel = max(vowel_list)
    location_most_vowel = vowel_list.index(max_vowel) 
    country_most_vowel = countries[234]
    return country_most_vowel
```

I've read some things about n largest, but most of the solutions I've come across is not something that has been covered in the course yet. (This current assignment is to practice with for loops) I'm curious about the information I haven't learned yet, but I doubt it would be something to get into, without understanding the basics.

What are some beginner tools/ functions/ techniques I could use for this?

Comment: can you add `countries` to the code?

Comment: Hi, If I say this correctly, the course imported the list from another (json)file and used 'from helpers import get_countries' 

(I'm sorry if this sounds vague, I'm very new to programming!)

Comment: I have used my own country list and provided a simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look below (using my own country list)

```
countries = [
    {"name": "Afghanistan", "code": "AF"},
    {"name": "land Islands", "code": "AX"},
    {"name": "Albania", "code": "AL"},
    {"name": "Algeria", "code": "DZ"},
    {"name": "American Samoa", "code": "AS"},
    {"name": "AndorrA", "code": "AD"},
    {"name": "Angola", "code": "AO"},
    {"name": "Anguilla", "code": "AI"},
    {"name": "Antarctica", "code": "AQ"},
    {"name": "Antigua and Barbuda", "code": "AG"},
    {"name": "Argentina", "code": "AR"},
    {"name": "Armenia", "code": "AM"},
    {"name": "Aruba", "code": "AW"},
    {"name": "Australia", "code": "AU"},
    {"name": "Austria", "code": "AT"},
    {"name": "Azerbaijan", "code": "AZ"},
    {"name": "Bahamas", "code": "BS"},
    {"name": "Bahrain", "code": "BH"},
    {"name": "Bangladesh", "code": "BD"},
    {"name": "Barbados", "code": "BB"},
    {"name": "Belarus", "code": "BY"},
    {"name": "Belgium", "code": "BE"},
    {"name": "Belize", "code": "BZ"}
]
result = []
vowels = {"A", "a", "E", "e", "I", "i", "O", "o", "U", "u"}
for country in countries:
    c = country['name']
    cnt = 0
    for x in c:
        if x in vowels:
            cnt += 1
    result.append((c, cnt))
result = sorted(result, key=lambda x: x[1],reverse=True)[:3]
print(result)
```

output (Top 3)

```
[('Antigua and Barbuda', 8), ('American Samoa', 7), ('Australia', 5)]
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for sharing your insightful solution with me. Are there any techniques that can be used without key, lambda and reverse? Unfortunately, I haven't learned about these yet, so it's a bit difficult to follow along.

Comment: @Jay Try to read https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#key-functions and I hope it will be more clear to you.

Comment: Thank you very much!! I will read it through, will try my best.